# Send Email Based on bgColor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would need to examine Google Sheet's range of cells based on their background color (bgColor). Let's say if the bgColor is red then email should be send to list of email addresses (of collaborators).

Answer (score 0):

This is really a simple one, I used the logger to know the code of the cell color I had in my sheet, in this case red is code `#fff2cc` which is not pure red but since I'm color blind it looks like red for me ;-)

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var bg = sh.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  for(var n = 0 ; n<bg.length;n++){
    Logger.log(bg[n][0]);
    if (bg[n][0] == '#fff2cc'){ // I checked only column A (index 0), change here for other column
      var bgCol = n+1;
      MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'test color','BGcolor in cell A'+bgCol+' is #fff2cc !');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I will have a look on it.